# How to convert the numbers in file names if it was an object? I tried str_replace but it doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, converters

I'm trying to convert the numbers in file names from Arabic to English, because some of the customers uploaded files that contains Arabic numbers, so when I tried to download it I couldn't, it shows some errors.

After using str_replace function it changes the names to:

> phpF77E.tmp

I want it only to convert the Arabic numbers to English not change it to "tmp" file.

**Upload and store file function:**

```
public function storeCv(Request $request, $trainee_id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'cv' => 'required_without:file',
        'file' => 'required_without:cv',
    ]);

    $trainee = Trainee::findOrFail($trainee_id);
    $file = $request->file('cv') ?: $request->file('file');
    $convert_num = $this->convert($file);
    $uploaded_file = $trainee->uploadToFolder($convert_num, 'cv');

    // When the other has been filled, mark the application as pending approval from the administration.
    if ($trainee->cv_url) {
        $trainee->status = Trainee::STATUS_PENDING_APPROVAL;
        $trainee->save();
    }

    return $uploaded_file;
}
```

**uploadToFolder function:**

```
public function uploadToFolder($file, $folder)
{
    return $this->addMedia($file)
        ->withAttributes([
            'team_id' => $this->team_id,
        ])
        ->toMediaCollection($folder);
}
```

**Convert function:**

```
public function convert($str)
{
    $arabic_eastern = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];
    $arabic_western = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    return preg_replace($arabic_eastern, $arabic_western, $str);
}
```

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Laravel, here is the answer:

```
if (! $file->isValid()) {
    // the file is not valid
}
$originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$filename = $this->convert($originalName); // you function
$fullpathoffile = $file->storeAs('', $filename, ['disk' => 'folderSomething']); //define in filesystems.php
$filename = basename($fullpathoffile);
```

config/filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [
    'folderSomething' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path('uploads/folder-something'),
     ],
 ...
```